# In Spring MVC how do you store user input and reproduce it later on?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, variables, spring-mvc

In one of my JSPs I get the user to enter some details about themselves. When they click submit I want the page that it redirects to, to remember the variable and then print it out.

e.g.

```
(register.jsp) Username: Barney
(welcome.jsp) Welcome Barney
(register.jsp) Username: Vernon
(welcome.jsp) Hello Vernon
```

Current code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(ModelMap map, HttpSession session,
@RequestParam(value="givenUser") String givenUser) {   
session.setAttribute("ans", givenUser);
map.addAttribute("displayAnswer", givenUser);
map.put("givenUser", givenUser);
return "register";
}
}
```

Request mapping for welcome:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome() {
return "welcome"; 
}
```

and then in welcome.jsp I have: Hello ${givenAnswer}

register.jsp which once the link inside is clicked, goes to welcome.jsp

this is register.jsp

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>SPRING ####### WEB</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>SUCCESSFUL REDIRECTION!!!</h2>
    <p>Register</p>

    <form action="/HelloSpring/welcome" method="post">
      Username:  <input type="text" name="givenUser" >
      Firstname: <input type="text" name="givenPassword">
      Surname:   <input type="text" name="givenSurname" >
      Password:  <input type="password" name="givenPassword">
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SPRING ####### WEB</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Spring Page Redirection</h2>
<p>Welcome ${givenUser}, your password is ${givenPassword}</p>


</body>
</html>
```

so my question is what have i not included because it currently just fires a blank when the user submits details

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow :) so what have you tried so far ? Read [ask]

Comment: <input type="text" name="howareyou" value="${status.value}"><br>

<p>Glad you are feeling ${status.value}!</p>

Comment: does that print anyhting . Edit the question with your spring controller code?

Comment: What you want is an iteraction between 3 elements : a form in a JSP, a controller, and a second JSP. You showed the controller but as my crystal ball is currently out of use, could you at least show the form ?

Comment: what would you like to see? the controller is displayed in my code already. do you want the answer.jsp with the form that is inside there?

Comment: i have added both forms so now you should be able to see 2 forms, and a controller thus making the required 3 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUCCESS! apparently it needed ${ param.elc }. why is this not on any tutorials and how come no one knew about it? im a bit skeptical still but it's doing as required.
thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can post the `userinput` attribute to the Controller and then send the value back in ModelMap.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello1(ModelMap map,@RequestParam String userInput){
    /*your code goes here*/     
    map.put("userInput",userInput);
    return "jsp1";   //first jsp name
}
```

and use it in jsp using expression language.

Hello `{userInput}!!`

Comment: im sure it is much simpler than that. there is definitely a way to do it using jstl but it has escaped my mind currently!

Comment: no it should be done in the above way alone . remember spring is a mvc , you cant make it to be displayed like embedding `<html>` tag inside the servlet

Comment: ok so I have sorted the first part. now it is just a matter of displaying it. how can this be achieved? surely the variables need to be linked somehow so that when i say Hello{userInput} it will know what the userInput refers to?

Comment: When you put the value of userInput into your ModelMap using  `map.put("key",value)` it is accessible in the returned jsp using the key.In the above code the key is "userInput" so when you will access ${userInput} it will give the value.

Comment: i have added my current code to the question section. I am still just getting Hello and then blank. can you see what i have done wrong?

Comment: @RedBaron-Change the `@RequestParam(value="howareyou")` in the controller to match with the input element in your jsp and change the request method to post  `method = RequestMethod.POST` as you have used post method in your jsp.

Comment: @NavishSharma-I have changed the method to POST but what should i change the RequestParam to? currently it is the name of the jsp (howareyou.jsp) that contains a user input box and the value the user inputs into that box and then hits submit should be the value that appears on the next jsp (answer.jsp)

Comment: @RedBaron- The annotation @RequestParam specifies the request paramter which would have  been posted from the jsp which calls the current request mapping. For your case since you used the input element ` <input type="text" name="howareyou" >` in howareyou.jsp ,the name attribute is "howareyou" so use this in the @RequestParam(value="howareyou")

Comment: @NavishSharma-So I have now done that and it is still returning a blank on the redirect page. it returns "Welcome , your password is". It should return "Welcome Moses, your password is VM11ST". I will reedit the code in the question so you can see everyone and maybe point out my error

Comment: @NavishSharma - all the code has now been posted into the question. any ideas why it is still not playing ball?

Comment: @RedBaron-Also post the request mapping of your controller which redirects to welcome.jsp

Comment: @NavishSharma-i have now added that request mapping. the only other request mapping is for 'home' and that looks exactly the same as the code for 'welcome', just the word home replaces the word welcome on all instances.

Comment: @RedBaron-You will need to add the ModelMap in the /welcome request mapping as well,the same way you did in the /register mapping.The variable put in model map is valid for only a jsp which is returned in that request mapping.

Comment: @NavishSharma-Can I just confirm how similar they should look? do i need reqparam and http session in that one too?
sorry, if they are simple questions but I am quite new to spring so just getting my head around it. and no idea why it is still not working and just displaying a simple variable on the redirected page. does yours work?

Comment: @RedBaron-You dont really require HttpSession unless you want something to be updated or retrieved from the session.For your case this mapping should work:                                              `@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String welcome(@RequestParam(value = "givenUser") String givenUser,
   ModelMap map) {
  map.put("givenUser", givenUser);
  return "welcome";
 }`

Comment: nope still no success unfortunately.
perhaps I have code in the wrong place?
HelloSpring is my project title.
Which has webpages, source packages, libraries and config files branching off it.
webpages -> web-inf -> applicationContext.xml dispatcher-servlet.xml & web.xml
webpages -> web-inf > jsp
source packages -> service -> webcontroller.xml

THIS IS SO IRRITATING NOW, WHY IS MY COMPUTING BEING SUCH AN ANNOYANCE?!

Answer (score 0):

The name in a `<input>` tag is what is used as request parameter name on form submission.

You should at least change your controller code to use correct parameter name :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/answer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String answer(ModelMap map, HttpSession session,
        @RequestParam("howareyou") String givenAnswer) {

                session.setAttribute("ans", givenAnswer);
                map.addAttribute("displayAnswer", givenAnswer);
                map.put("givenAnswer", givenAnswer);      

            return "answer";
        }

}
```

I also removed unused parameter `req` since Spring gives you directly the `HttpSession`. And it is normally no use to add the same object twice in the model. But I assume you were not sure of what was correct and tried both - any of them is correct and is enough :-)

Comment: when i tried this it started kicking off and underlying session in read saying 'cannot find symbol' in net beans. any reason why?

Comment: @RedBaron Sorry, I left parenthesis that should not exist. Answer edited

Comment: thanks for the effort. it's still being annoying and not generating it as I wish it to. not sure what's missing. only thing is if i've put code in the wrong place.

Comment: Can i just ask why you use modelmap instead of model. and what the difference is? and can we use both?

Comment: @RedBaron I use `ModelMap` here because you used in in your example. I cannot tell you which is better. I generally use Model because it saves 3 characters to type ;-)